# Detect by terminal the camera is in use?

Tags: macos, camera, zsh

How can I read out on macOS Monterey, Ventura and Sonoma whether the camera in the MacBook is currently in use?

I found this command, but it doesn't work on x86 or ARM with macOS Ventura and Sonoma

`lsof -n | grep "AppleCamera"`

Does anyone have any other idea how I can find out whether an application is currently using the camera?

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to detect that the camera is in use.

Comment: The video reactions have been there since Sonoma. 
I would like to deactivate these by default on all our Macs.

I came across this script on [Jamf Nation](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/disable-video-reaction-macos-14/m-p/302709#M265816), which also works, but only when the camera is not in use.

So that the script which is to deactivate the video reactions does not run when the camera is in use, I am looking for a solution how I can find out if the camera is in use or not.